# Give (click) attribute only if condition is met ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic3

I"m pulling data from an API right now and depending on if the user is logged in or not I want to display a login prompt. I can do this by having two divs each with their own `*ngIf="cond"` but this is a lot of duplicate code. Is there a way using Ionic 3 + Angular to only have the `(click)` attribute if a condition is met, otherwise leave it off?

Any help would be great.

Comment: you could set display to none on the button by using `Renderer`'s  `setElementStyle` to add `'display', 'none'` to the button when the condition is met, and change it to `block` or whatever it needs to be when the condition is not met. If you provide some code I can show you how it works

Comment: Another way to do it would be to still handle the `click` event, and add a condition as the first line of the handler `yourMethod() { if(shouldLeave) return; // ...}` to check if you need to do something or just ignore the click